# I keep getting an A2008 error for line 57. I cant seem to find what the error is. 'exit' should be fine

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

```
TITLE AsmSelectionSort Procedure (AsmSelectionSort.asm)


.586
.model flat, C

AsmSelectionSort PROTO, value:DWORD, arrayPTR:PTR DWORD, count :DWORD

.code
AsmSelectionSort PROC USES edi, value:DWORD, arrayPTR:PTR DWORD, count:DWORD
     

LOCAL first : DWORD, last : DWORD, mid : DWORD

mov first, 0
mov eax, count
dec eax
mov last, eax
mov edi, value
mov ebx, arrayPTR

L1 :
mov eax, first
cmp eax, last
jg L4

mov eax, last
add eax, first
shr eax, 1
mov mid, eax

mov esi, mid
shl esi, 2
mov edx, [ebx + esi]

cmp edx, edi
jge L2
mov eax, mid
inc eax
mov first, eax
jmp L1

L2 :
     jle L3
     mov eax, mid
     dec eax
     mov last, eax
     jmp L1

     L3 : mov eax, mid
     jmp L5

     L4 : mov eax, -1

     L5 : ret

exit
     AsmSelectionSort ENDP
     END
```

Comment: Why would you assume it's fine?  Did you define it as a macro or include a file that does?  It's not an x86 instruction, and apparently it's not a MASM built-in macro.

Comment: @PeterCordes : `.startup` and `.exit` (not `exit`) are directives in MASM, although they don't apply to 32-bit code segments which would produce an error here since they are using the FLAT memory model. The OP should just remove `exit` .

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Irvine32 defines an `exit` macro (http://www.math.uaa.alaska.edu/~afkjm/cs221/handouts/irvine3.pdf) that you can use instead of returning from main.  But yes, since there's already a `ret`, putting it *after* that is 100% pointless.

Comment: @PeterCordes : this isn't including the irvine32 library.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I did not need to use exit since I am using ret.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Indeed, that's probably the bug.  `exit` was probably copy/pasted from code that did use Irvine32, in a tutorial or other example or skeleton / template.  Although maybe not; indenting like a directive instead of instruction might indicate a different misconception.  Anyway, the archaeology doesn't matter much.